# Yeoman/gruntjs angularjs and directives with html files in the folder

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-contrib-copy

i'm using `yeoman` as tool for mantaining the app organized. Since i've many directives i did not use the standard way the `yeoman` generate the directive, thus `scripts/directive/name.js` for the code and `views/template_directive.html` for the template.

I instead did this:
`scripts/directive/my-directive` and inside i've the `js` and `html` file. 
[here a screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/affoi0rkztq8wd4/Screenshot%202015-07-10%2010.52.10.png?dl=0)

Now, when i `serve` everything works well, the problem araises when i run the `build`. the `js` of the directives ends up in the `vendor.js` but the html page still points to `scripts/directive/my-directive/template_directive.html` which is not part of the dist.

What I should (probably, if there's better options more than welcome) do is:

- copy the `html` in the view folder
- change the refence in the js of the directive

*or*

- find a way to have the `html` files in the same folder also for the dist (recreate all the `/directives/<directive>/<template>.html`)

the question is:

- what's the "correct" solution
- what's the command to change in gruntjs to make it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like this (not sure if it's "correct" but works)

add this in the `copy` section

```
..
{
 expand: true,
 dot: true,
 cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/directives',
 src: ['*/*.html'],
 dest:'<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/directives'
}
..
```

add this to the `minhtml` conf

```
files: [{
   ...
   src: [..,'scripts/directives/*/*.html'],
   ...
}]
```